# How to say I ranked 2nd in a competition?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing my resume and, in the group projects section, I want to say - in a very short way - that I participated in a competition and among 5 teams, mine ranked 2nd.

To express that, can I say, referring to that project: "**2nd placed out of 5 teams competing**" ?
Is it grammatically correct?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Placed second out of five teams competing."

Or, a little more colloquial, "came in second out of five teams competing."

Answer (score 3):

You can say that you were *runner-up* in the 5-team competition.

> **runner-up** *noun*
>   A competitor or team taking second place in a contest.
>   ‘he was runner-up in the 200 m individual medley’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/runner-up)